# I have downloaded a static built of a linux program. Where should I put the man pages?

Tags: ffmpeg, manpage

I have downloaded a static built of a linux program (ffmpeg) I want to use in my Ubuntu 14.04

I just copy the executable (ffmpeg) into /usr/local/bin and the program works. I have been doing so for long now with this program. The author of the static built updates it very often.

But I have no man pages. Inside the directory where the static built comes, there is a directory called manpages. I think I might copy the files inside that directory (or the directory itself) to some location in my hard drive and from that moment I would be able to type in a console:
man ffmpeg

Where should I put those files?

Remark: I don't want to delve into the complexities of compiling the program on my own (gathering information about the components I should include in the compilation, etc) and I don't want to use the fork (avconv) of ffmpeg that unluckily comes with my ubuntu because of the multiple bugs I have experience with it, and because of its lack of some ffmpeg features (video de-shaking!). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the paths on which man pages are searched, you can use the `manpath` command (see also [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/q/318555/216900)). In (my) Ubuntu 14.04 system, this delivers the following search path:

```
/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man
```

So you could just put the man pages into `/usr/local/share/man`.

I’m not sure which static build of ffmpeg you are using; if it‘s [the one](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) currently mentioned on [the official ffmpeg page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-linux), then this will probably not work, though. The `manpages` directory of that distribution is not in the required `man` page format; the `.txt` files only contain *dumps* of man pages. Compare these `.txt` files to existing man pages under `/usr/share/man`, for example.

Comment: It is that compilation. Therefore those man pages will not work and there is little to add here. Thanks for your answer.